# How to use this strange operator with double factorials of the photon number operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation

In a few quantum physics papers I saw an operator proportional to this one:
$$\hat{N}=\frac{(\hat{n}-1)!!}{\hat{n}!!},$$
where $\hat{n}=\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$ and $!!$ is the [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).
Any idea on how to apply such an operator on e.g. a Fock state $|n\rangle$ or a coherent state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{(\hat{n}-1)!!}{\hat{n}!!}|n\rangle =\frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}|n\rangle$$
Regarding coherent states it is enough expanding them in terms of states with defined $n$ and using linearity.

All that immediately arises from the general spectral theory: If $\psi_a$ is an eigenvector of a self-adjoint operator $A$ with eigenvalue $a\in \mathbb R$ and $f$ is any (measurable,  real or complex valued) function over $\mathbb R$, **by definition** 
$$f(A) \psi_a := f(a) \psi_a\:.$$

Comment: Could you expand on how that works?  For the operator in the denominator do you expand that in a Taylor series around $n$?

Comment: Yes, for the numerator I agree, but I was concerned about the denominator. How do you exactly compute $\frac{1}{\hat{n}!!}|n\rangle$?

Comment: Just replacing the operator for the number inside the ket.

Comment: @garyp I answered your question completing my answer. Taylor series has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: Indeed it was :)

Comment: I didn't know that definition.  Good to know.